# jQuery allways Post null to Action in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have a problem and I don't know what is the issue. 
I am constructing a Json object and I want to post it back with `$.ajax`. The problem is I always get null in my Action.
here is Ajax Part :

```
            $("input[type=button]#ajax-editor-save").click(function() {

            var hotelPropertyAssignModel = new Object();
            hotelPropertyAssignModel.Hotel_Id = 1;
            hotelPropertyAssignModel.HotelProperties = new Array();

            $("input.ajax-editor[data-edited=true]").each(function() {
                var hotelPropertyValue = new Object();
                hotelPropertyValue.HotelProperty_Id = $(this).attr("data-hotelPropertyId");
                hotelPropertyValue.Language = $(this).attr("data-lang");
                hotelPropertyValue.Value = $(this).attr("value");
                hotelPropertyAssignModel.HotelProperties.push(hotelPropertyValue);
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action( "SetProperties" )',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(hotelPropertyAssignModel)
            });
        });
```

and here is Action:

```
[AcceptVerbs( HttpVerbs.Post )]
[HttpPost]
public void SetProperties ( string hotelPropertyAssignModel )
{

}
```

I changed the parameter to string to validate how json is coming. I get null when I replace it with correct model too!
anybody can help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you set the proper contentType:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action( "SetProperties" )',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(hotelPropertyAssignModel)
});
```

The `dataType` parameter that you were using indicates the response type, not the request type. You don't need it if your controller action properly sets the Content-Type response header which it normally does if you are returning for example a JsonResult.

But from what I can see your controller action is declared as void which obviously is wrong. Controller actions must return action results. If you don't care about the content, simply use an `EmptyResult`:

```
[AcceptVerbs( HttpVerbs.Post )]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SetProperties ( string hotelPropertyAssignModel )
{
    ...
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Also there's another very serious problem with your controller action. It is taking a string argument instead of a view model!!! I don't know how you were possibly expecting to bind a JSON request to some string.

So, **immediately** define a view model that will match the JSON structure you are willing to send:

```
public class HotelAssignmentViewModel
{
    public int Hotel_Id { get; set; } 
    public HotelPropertyViewModel[] HotelProperties { get; set; }
}

public class HotelPropertyViewModel
{
    public int HotelProperty_Id { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public string Value  { get; set; }
}
```

and then have your controller action take this view model as parameter:

```
[AcceptVerbs( HttpVerbs.Post )]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SetProperties ( HotelAssignmentViewModel model )
{
    ...
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

I also notice another problem with your code. You seem to have subscribed to the click event of some DOM element to trigger the AJAX request but you never cancel the default action by returning false from this event. So for example if this is a submit button or an anchor, it will simply redirect the browser away from the page leaving no time for your AJAX request to execute. So make sure you cancel this default action by returning false from your click handler:

```
$("input[type=button]#ajax-editor-save").click(function() {
    ...
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Then the JSON structure you are sending is not matching your view model. By the way which version of ASP.NET MVC are you using? If it is 2 or earlier, don't forget that it doesn't support JSON requests out of the box. You will have to write a custom JsonValueProviderFactory as Phil Haack explains in this blog post: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx If you are using ASP.NET MVC 3 or higher you don't need it because it is built-in.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried both of your solutions. unfortunatly It still doesen't work! I am using MVC 4. It means I should write that JsonValueProviderFactory I think!

Comment: Oh but wait a minute, I haven't noticed your controller action. It is taking a string argument instead of a view model!!!! I will update my answer right now.

Comment: Alright answer updated. You should define a view model. I don't know how were you expecting to bind a JSON to a string parameter.

Comment: thank for your respond again! but as I mentioned in my question I changed the model to string to verify wheater It is failing to bind the data correctly or the problem is something else. I have that viewModel in code.

Comment: shouldn't string parameter get the json data as raw input?

Comment: Wait, I see yet another problem with your code :-) Let me update my answer. You should also cancel the default action of the click event by returning false from it. In your case it seems it is a standard button and not a submit button but it's generally good practice to do so.